# getJSON For Loop on each div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var klient = 'tokenkeyvaluehere';
    var firstlink = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,posts&access_token='+klient;
    $.getJSON(firstlink, function(dayta){

        var haitchteamel = "";
        var el = $('#facebookapi'); 
            $.each(dayta.posts.data, function(key, val){

                function firstpart(){return val.message;}

        var secondlink = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/'+val.id+'?fields=attachments&access_token='+klient;      
                    $.ajax({
                        url: secondlink,
                        success: function(result){
                            var theterms = result.attachments.data[0].media.image.src;
                            for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('bisniss').length; i++){
                                $('.picture').eq(i).html('<img src="'+theterms+'"/>');

                            }
                        }
                    });

                    haitchteamel += `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 bisniss">
                    <p>`+firstpart()+`</p>
                    <div class="picture"></div>
                    </div>`;
            });
        el.html(haitchteamel);
    });
});
```

I am having a bit of an issue with my for loops. I have added my full code for context, but the only part I have an issue with is on `$('.picture')`.

For some context, I am using the Facebook API to get each post, as seen on `firstlink` and `firstpart()`. Using the `val.id` that I get from this call, I use the info to get the attachment(ie photos) accompanying each post.

My current problem is that `.picture` retrieves only one of the pictures from my posts and spread them throughout every `.picture` div. My goal is to have only the accompanying pictures of each post.

There is clearly something that I am not understanding about the use of For Loops. Either that, or there is a problem with my dom implementation over `.picture`.

Comment: loop is synch while ajax call is asynch use call back in success